# What edition of CRC mathematical Tables was the last to contain logarithmic tables?

Tags: mathematics, reference-request

I recently tried to ask about when the last book was published that contained logarithmic tables. From what I understand, the question was unclear because it is unclear what published means.

So, let me try with what I hope is a well-defined questions. What edition of CRC mathematical Tables was the last to contain logarithmic tables? The current edition ([31st edition](http://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9781584882916)) does not contain the logarithmic tables.

Edit: For those who don't know, logarithmic tables are tables with values of logarithms. As an example see [this webpage](http://www.sliderules.info/a-to-z/log-tables.htm) or this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_table#Tables_of_logarithms).

Answer (score 1):

According to the table of contents,

http://www.mathtable.com/smtf/smtf30_toc.html

30-th edition contains logarithms.

Comment: I can't find the table of logarithms in the table of contents..

Comment: It is 6.6 in the table of contents, though it is not clear whether this is a table or just formulas.

Comment: 6.6 in the table of centents isn't the logarithmic tables, but just some list of functions.

Answer (score 1):

Bradis mathematical tables, 13th edition, published in 2010, contains logarithms:

http://www.alleng.ru/d/math/math863.htm

Answer (score 1):

I have the 28th Edition of CRC Standard Mathematical Tables (1988) and the log tables begin on page 161.

Comment: Can you provide, say, a hyperlink to an online source of the book (if possible) so it's easier to verify? It's okay if you can't (e.g. for copyright reasons - no online copies are allowed).

Comment: I only have a hard copy of the book.